# how to make cycle renders look more octane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, soft-body, octane-render-engine

I'm quite fascinated with the soft view in renders with octane
[image]

all octane renders have a particular light and softness; somehow, I cannot reproduce that blender cycles.
Any suggestions on how to make cycles render look like Octane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an opinion, but I would start by changing View Transform to "Standard" and using "Medium low-contrast" for the *Look*.

For the material, use a small amount of *Subsurface Scattering* (colored to match your basecolor). Increase specular to 1. For even better results, use a Clearcoat value close to 1 (small difference, but still looks better - not pictured).

[image: Soft]

Further softening can be accomplished with any combination of these nodes in the compositor - The defocus and blur provide further "softening" of the sheen, and the Glare emulates bloom:

[image: Composit]

Going even further, one of the things that looks characteristic of the Octane render is what appears to be colored Ambient Occlusion - to get this in Cycles, enable AO as a render pass under *View Layers*, and then from the compositor, you can use a Color Balance node to add color to it (not a *huge* difference, but it all adds up):

[image: AO]

Comment: This is incorrect. The question asked about Cycles specifically but only EEVEE has a bloom setting

Comment: @cat40 My bad, I missed the cycles part  - serves me righht for answering a Q at 5AM ;) I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChristopherBennett 
I noticed that perfect lighting and adjusting the settings to get "colored ambient occlusion" does give somewhat octane feel